# (Angular 7, Chrome extension) Why does a mat dialog render correctly in a webpage, but not in a chrome extension? (With reproduction repo)

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension, dialog, angular-material

So I have some Angular 7 code that makes extensive use of material dialogs, all works great when I view it as a webpage, but when I try to load it as a chrome extension, everything but the dialogs render correctly. When a dialog gets opened, the whole extension window gets a small width. I should note that the dialog does appear, everything just gets so small it isnt useable at all.

I have tried to replicate this behaviour when viewing the webpage in a small window, both with and without the responsive settings from chrome.

I think this might have something to do with permission, but I dont know what I should change. However I dont get any errors on the chrome://extension page, nor is anything logged to the console.

I have the following permissions and csp in my manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
```

How I use dialogs:

I inject `MatDialog` into the constructor of a service, create a function for that service that calls `open(DialogComponent, {width: '25em', height: '25em', disableClose: true})` on the injected MatDialog. (I get the settings from another service) and I return the `afterClosed().toPromise()`.

The DialogComponent gets a `MatDialogRef<DialogComponent>` injected in its contructor. Some of my dialogs call the `dialogRef.close` with parameters, some dont use parameters.

I added a github reproduction repository:
https://github.com/erikknaake/dialog-reproduction/tree/master/dialog-reproduction

I should mention this happens in the default_popup: `"browser_action": { "default_popup": "index.html" }`

Chrome extension render:

[image]

Expected render:

[image]

Everything else just works as expected:

[image]

If you need futher information please ask.

Comment: Without an [MCVE](/help/mcve) this is unlikely to get an answer. Assuming this is inside the browserAction (or pageAction) popup, make sure you've checked the [correct console](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38920982) (it's a separate window, not the same as web page) for errors.

Comment: I have checked the separate windows console. I should mention this happens in the default_popup. ```"browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "index.html"
  },
```. I will try to create a reproduction repo in the coming days

Comment: I edited the question by adding a reproduction repository

Comment: It sets `<html>` style to `position: fixed;` via .cdk-global-scrollblock rule. Remove it and you're good.

Comment: How would I remove that from my code, I dont want to edit the build files since I am still in development phase?

Comment: I have no idea so I can only assume it should be trivial. At the worst you can simply override the position via an inline style attribute or an additional CSS rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wOxxOms comment was right, after adding

```
.cdk-global-scrollblock {
  position: relative !important;
}
```

To the styles.css the problem was fixed.